# I want to change the font size of bullet and numbering list in ssrs

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

In my SSRS Report I want

1. Red
2. Green
3. Blue
4. Pink

with size 6pt by using bullet and numbering.

the numbering size should also 6pt.

Please help me how to do so in SSRS.

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: And what is Red, Green, Blue, Pink?

Comment: I tried <ol style="font-size:6px"><li>.........</li> in expression

Comment: THESE Are just items of my list for example\

Comment: I also tried <font style="font-size:6px"> <ol><li>.........</li></ol></font> in expression